# jQuery - How to change the name of a class using .attr() when I'm referring to a class and not an id?

Tags: jquery, html

**HTML**

```
<span class="sentiment-info"></span>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.sentiment-info').attr('class', 'sentiment neutral');
var val = foo.attr('class');
alert(val);
```

EDIT: Okay so everything I said before is unimportant. Let's make this question simpler. What is wrong with my syntax here? I'm getting undefined.

EDIT2: So it appears '.sentiment-info' doesn't work to change the class, but '#sentiment-info' would. How to fix this?

EDIT3: Solution:

```
var foo = $('.sentiment-info');
foo.attr('class', 'sentiment neutral');
var val = foo.attr('class');
alert(val);
```

Comment: What's the real goal here?

Comment: What does `sentiment` equal? Are you trying to append a class?

Comment: Why not to try `$('.sentiment-info').toggleClass('sentiment ' + sentiment);` ?

Comment: If you're getting undefined for your class, it means `sentiment` has not been defined previously

Comment: a very sentimental question

Comment: _remove the class name, but not the class itself_ This... doesn't make sense...

Comment: Well, I found that .remove() removes the class itself. But all I want to do is change the name.

Comment: So you're trying to 'replace' `sentiment-info` with `sentiment-sentiment`? What will you do for a selector once you change it?

Comment: You cannot change the name of a class. Maybe what you want to do is change the class of an element, or add a class, or remove a class from the element.

Comment: In response to your edit, you changed the class, so that selector won't work anymore.

Comment: So how can I get it to work instead?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you want.. You could add a class that doesn't change and use that as a selector, you could leave your `sentiment-info` class there even after adding your `neutral` class, or you could give the element an id and use that as a selector.

Comment: Save a reference to the returned value: `var foo = $('.sentiment-info')` and use that var instead.

Comment: @dc5 Please look at my edit, It's still undefined.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the class completely,

```
$('.sentiment-info').removeClass(<classname>);
```

To reassign a different class, use

```
$('.sentiment-info').attr('class',<classname>);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your edit, I think this is what you're asking for:

```
$('.sentiment-info')
    .removeClass('sentiment-info') 
    .addClass('sentiment')
    .addClass(sentiment);
```

If `sentiment` was `positive`, it would change

```
<span class="sentiment-info sentiment-class"></span>
```

to

```
<span class="sentiment-class sentiment positive"></span>
```

Comment: This answer is close to what I'm looking for, except `sentiment-info` is only going to be removed once, and after that it's either going to be `sentiment positive` `sentiment neutral` or `sentiment negative`

Comment: @dtgee What should happen instead?

Comment: After that, it will switch around to another sentiment. For example, `sentiment neutral` becomes `sentiment positive`. But that's not important. Check for my new edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$('span.sentiment-info').toggleClass('className');
```

Comment: @dumass - Be careful there, as you're coming along pretty insulting. It reads like your name is the end of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.sentiment-class').toggleClass('sentiment ' + sentiment);
```

So the classes you placed on it previously will always be there, and `'sentiment ' + sentiment` will be toggled on/off.

so:

```
<span class="sentiment-info sentiment-class"></span>
```

will become:

```
<span class="sentiment-info sentiment-class sentiment positive"></span>
```

and then if toggled will go back to:

```
<span class="sentiment-info sentiment-class"></span>
```

If you want `sentiment-info` removed, call it like so:

```
$('.sentiment-class').removeClass('sentiment-info').toggleClass('sentiment ' + sentiment);
```

Or if you're wanting that toggled opposite of your sentiment you can:

```
$('.sentiment-class').toggleClass('sentiment-info').toggleClass('sentiment ' + sentiment);
```